# UICollectionView doesn't display any image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to display image from documents directory in UICollectionView, everything works fine, but no image appears

```
- (void)viewDidLoad

{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Initialize recipe image array

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];



    NSArray *dirContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];


    NSMutableArray *image = [NSMutableArray array];


    for (NSString *tString in dirContents) {

        if ([tString hasSuffix:@".png"]) {

            [image addObject:tString];


            listeImages = [NSArray arrayWithArray:image];


        }

    }


}


- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return listeImages.count;



}


- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];



    UIImageView *listeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];

    UILabel *LabelView = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:110];

    LabelView.text = [listeImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    listeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[listeImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

   NSLog(@" List UIImageView listeImageView.image  %@",listeImageView.image);
```

cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

```
  cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"photo-frame.png"]];



     NSLog(@" List NSArray *listeImages %@",listeImages);

    cell.tag = indexPath.row;

    return cell;

}
```

with this piece of code, displays the correct UICollectionView UILabel well but no image is displayed.

I use this line of code to store my image in listeImageView.image.

```
 UIImageView *listeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    listeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[listeImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Here are the results of my NSLog:

```
2014-10-11 09:46:31.117 imgapp[2803:60b]  List NSArray *listeImages;  (
    "image10102014233607.png",
    "image10102014233616.png",
    "image10102014233627.png"
)
2014-10-11 09:46:31.158 imgapp[2803:60b]  List UIImageView listeImageView.image  (null)
2014-10-11 09:46:31.171 imgapp[2803:60b]  List UIImageView listeImageView.image  (null)
2014-10-11 09:46:31.178 imgapp[2803:60b]  List UIImageView listeImageView.image  (null)
```

any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Your NSLog-statement in numberOfItemsInSection will never be called. There should never be code after a return-statement. Swap those two lines.

Answer (score 1):

You have below,

```
listeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[listeImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

But your doing,

```
  cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"photo-frame.png"]];
```

Why your not using your listeImageView as below:-

```
cell.backgroundView = listeImageView;
```

That should get you the image.

**UPDATE** :-

```
 for (NSString *tString in dirContents) {

    if ([tString hasSuffix:@".png"]) {

              **[image addObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:tString] ];  //Do this as in below line you were not create a image object which you are trying to get.**

       //Also check your image array for object, that is it getting stored or not.
       //     [image addObject:tString];

    }

}

 listeImages = [NSArray arrayWithArray:image];  //Do this after you have added all objects in your image mutable array and not in for loop as this will initialise it many tiems depending on your loop run count.
```

Comment: thanks for answer but the line code 'code' cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"photo-frame.png"]];'code' is just for displaying e photo frame arround any image and it's working.

Comment: @IndiaNasirJones So if your query is resolved then you could close your query.

Comment: I just edit the code with new element, the problem seems to be that my listeImageView do not stock my images, but I do not understand why?

Comment: @IndiaNasirJones I have updated my post check it out. Fixed your issue so give it a run !

Comment: Could u share the error ? Also what exact are you getting in tString variable ?

Comment: 'code'2014-10-11 14:51:59.257 imgapp[3954:60b] tString = image10102014233607.png
2014-10-11 14:51:59.258 imgapp[3954:60b] tString = image10102014233616.png
2014-10-11 14:51:59.258 imgapp[3954:60b] tString = image10102014233627.png
2014-10-11 14:51:59.258 imgapp[3954:60b] tString = image11102014130714.png
2014-10-11 14:51:59.259 imgapp[3954:60b] tString = image11102014135050.png
2014-10-11 14:51:59.297 imgapp[3954:60b]  listeImages = (
    "image10102014233607.png",
    "image10102014233616.png",
    "image10102014233627.png",
    "image11102014130714.png",
    "image11102014135050.png"
)'code'

Comment: I have updated code and also I assume that tString is file path, and I am now creating UIImage with imageWithContentsOfFile method. Also pass the full path of that and not just **tString = image10102014233607.png**

Comment: When i test it, i have this result      2014-10-11 15:35:27.018 imgApp[4124:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

Comment: I have updated the code but still at which line did u faced this error.

Answer (score 0):

You're not adding your *listeImageView* to anything. 
Try it with

```
[cell addSubview:listeImageView];
```

or if you really want it to be the backgroundView

```
cell.backgroundView = listeImageView;
```

But it'd be much cleaner if you create a custom UICollectionViewCell-class where you can define what content this cell has.

Comment: thanks for answer but i added my listeImageView to the cell with this line code 'code'UIImageView *listeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];'code'
i try yours code line but is the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Have u tried to give background color to cell instead of backgroundview.do that once if possible with same code of yours!

Or
You can try like :-UIImageView *listeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
[cell bringviewtoFront:listeImageView ];

Answer (score 0):

You'd be much better off subclassing UICollectionViewCell, and setting up the subviews in a storyboard. Your code could be much cleaner this way:

```
static NSString *kCustomCellIdentifier = @"customcell";

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MYAPPCustomCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCustomCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Load custom image
    NSString *imageName = [listeImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if (imageName)
    {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
        if (image)
        {
            cell.customImageView.image = image;
        }
        else
        {
            // Set an empty state here
            cell.customImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"errorImage.png"];
        }
    }

    return cell;
}
```